# cant create Dataloader for cycle gans with two csv input files

Tags: pytorch

I have tried the code which is attached in the screen shot below. But I am not able to do it. How can i create Dataloader for cycle gans with this input data

Comment: There is no attached image. Also, please do not post screenshots of code. Post properly formatted code so others can copy/paste it if necessary.

Comment: @jodag so here is my code